# Efficient use of Choleski decomposition in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

This question is related to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/fast-computation-estimation-of-a-full-rank-linear-system/20242#20242) and this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14951/efficient-calculation-of-matrix-inverse-in-r)

I have two full rank matrices **A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>** each 
of dimension p x p and a p-vector y.

These matrices are closely related in the sense that 
matrix **A<sub>2</sub>** is a rank one update of matrix **A<sub>1</sub>**.

I'm interested in the vector

> β<sub>2</sub> | (β<sub>1</sub>, y, **A<sub>1</sub>**, **A<sub>2</sub>**, **A<sub>1</sub>**<sup>-1</sup>})

where

> β<sub>2</sub> = (**A<sub>2</sub>**' **A<sub>2</sub>**)<sup>-1</sup>(**A<sub>2</sub>**'y)

and

> β<sub>1</sub> = (**A<sub>1</sub>**' **A<sub>1</sub>**)<sup>-1</sup>(**A<sub>1</sub>**' y)

Now, in a previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/fast-computation-estimation-of-a-full-rank-linear-system/20242#20242) here I have been advised 
to estimate β<sub>2</sub> by the Choleski approach since the Choleski 
decomposition is easy to update using R functions such as `chud()` 
in package **SamplerCompare**.

Below are two functions to solve linear systems in R, the first one uses 
the `solve()` function and the second one the Choleski approach 
(the second one I can efficiently update).

```
fx01 <- function(ll,A,y) chol2inv(chol(crossprod(A))) %*% crossprod(A,y)

fx03 <- function(ll,A,y) solve(A,y)

p <- 5
A <- matrix(rnorm(p^2),p,p)
y <- rnorm(p)

system.time(lapply(1:1000,fx01,A=A,y=y))
system.time(lapply(1:1000,fx03,A=A,y=y))
```

My question is: for p small, both functions seems to be comparable 
(actually `fx01` is even faster). But as I increase p,
 `fx01` becomes increasingly slower so that for p = 100, 
 `fx03` is three times as fast as  `fx01`.

What is causing the performance deterioration of  `fx01` and can it 
be improved/solved (maybe my implementation of the Choleski is too naive? Shouldn't I be using functions of the Choleski constellation such as `backsolve`, and if yes, how?

1. `A %*% B` is the R lingo for matrix multiplication of A by B.
2. `crossprod(A,B)` is the R lingo for **A**' **B** (ie transpose of A matrix
   multiplying the matrix/vector B).
3. `solve(A,b)` solves for x the linear system **A** x=b.
4. `chol(A)` is the Choleski decomposition of a PSD matrix **A**.
5. `chol2inv`  computes (**X**' **X**)<sup>-1</sup> from the (R part) of the QR decomposition of **X**.

Comment: Ta da! Unicode and some markup. Not as convenient as LaTeX, but we make do with what we have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'fx01' implementation is, as you mentioned, somewhat naive and is performing far more work than the 'fx03' approach. In linear algebra (my apologies for the main StackOverflow not supporting LaTeX!), 'fx01' performs:

- B := A' A in roughly n^3 flops.
- L := chol(B) in roughly 1/3 n^3 flops.
- L := inv(L) in roughly 1/3 n^3 flops.
- B := L' L in roughly 1/3 n^3 flops.
- z := A y in roughly 2n^2 flops.
- x := B z in roughly 2n^2 flops.

Thus, the cost looks very similar to 2n^3 + 4n^2, whereas your 'fx03' approach uses the default 'solve' routine, which likely performs an LU decomposition with partial pivoting (2/3 n^3 flops) and two triangle solves (plus pivoting) in 2n^2 flops. Your 'fx01' approach therefore performs three times as much work asymptotically, and this amazingly agrees with your experimental results. Note that if A was real symmetric or complex Hermitian, that an LDL^T or LDL' factorization and solve would only require half as much work.

With that said, I think that you should replace your Cholesky update of A' A with a more stable QR update of A, as I just answered [in your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/fast-computation-estimation-of-a-full-rank-linear-system/20242#20242). A QR decomposition costs roughly 4/3 n^3 flops and a rank-one update to a QR decomposition is only O(n^2), so this approach only makes sense for general A when there is more than just one related solve that is simply a rank-one modification.

Comment: Sadly, yes, it was determined by the power-that-be that LaTeX rendering would slow down SO too much. You can look at my edit of the question for some tips on how to make do without. Awkward, but it works ok.

Comment: Jack Poulson, i haven't find an implementation of QR updating in R. Given what we have (updating of Cholesky decomposition is implemented) can you recommend a more efficient approach?

Comment: Jack Poulson:> in reality, there are many more than one rank one update of A. A is a general (real) matrix (not symmetric).

Comment: I would recommend implementing it yourself or switching to Octave or Matlab, which both have the routine. The A'A approach is not just less efficient, but also less stable, and it is a rank-2 update to A'A despite what someone said in your previous question.

Comment: Accidentally, it seems to be a reccuring mistake among statisticians (tough clearly the underlying claim is wrong, given my timing experiment, see for example page 15 here: stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/classes/248/homework.pdf). There appears to be some effort in the direction of linking R and Octave. I will try these and let you know. In any case, thanks for the help&pointers.